# foreach and for loop in PHP

Tags: php

am working on php loops and i find myself that i need to write a nested loop bur when i try to combine foreach and for loop it yield to unexpected result 
Here are my codes

```
       foreach ($district_ward as $key => $value) {
           $ward_ids = array_keys($district_ward[$key]);
           echo $key;
           for ($x = 0; $x < count($ward_ids)-1; $x++) {
               $district_village[$key]= array_merge($value[$ward_ids[$x]], $value[$ward_ids[$x+1]]);
           }               
        }
```

This gives me this

```
347
```

but when i print the value of $key within the for loop, that is

```
        foreach ($district_ward as $key => $value) {
           $ward_ids = array_keys($district_ward[$key]);
           for ($x = 0; $x < count($ward_ids)-1; $x++) {
   echo $key;
               $district_village[$key]= array_merge($value[$ward_ids[$x]], $value[$ward_ids[$x+1]]);
           }
        }
```

i get this

```
3
```

Comment: BTW: `array_keys($district_ward[$key])` → `array_keys($value)`

Comment: thanx, i endup writng that when i was trying to figure what might b the problem, thanx once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to guess that your 2nd and 3rd array are only one entry long. The condition for the loop specifies `$x < count($ward_ids) - 1`. If your array only has one entry, *one - 1* will make it loop 0 times. In other words, your inner loop is not executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing this to a html page? Are your keys 3, 4 and 7? They would appear as 347 if you were echoing to an html page.  Try

```
echo "$key<br />\n";
```

or even

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($district_ward)."</pre>";
```

before the loop to see what the array looks like.

Comment: the problem was never the display of the result rather the values that the i get within the for loop.. thnx for yo reply, you are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($district_ward as $key => $value) {
       $ward_ids = array_keys($district_ward[$key]);
       for ($x = 0; $x < count($ward_ids); $x++) {
           echo $key;
           $district_village[$key]= array_merge($value[$ward_ids[$x]], $value[$ward_ids[$x+1]]);
       }
    }
```

Should do the trick, this because you start at 0 up UNTIL the amount of $ward_ids
Let's say your $ward_ids has 1 entry, then you would have looped 0 till 0, so no loops at all,
And lets say it had 102 entries, then you would have looped 1-101, leaving 102 out since you started at 0.